# How to get acknowledgment for send/receive message in ejabbered/XMPP?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

How to know that message is deliver to other user using `XMPP framework` and `ejabberd`, we are using [XEP-0184](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html) class for Message Delivery Receipts , we send the receipts request while sending with the message but didn’t get any response.

My Query is should i need to configure anything on server (or any changes in `ejabberd.cfg` file) for that or any client side code we need to do.

Answer (score 6):

No, XEP-0184 is a purely client protocol, so there's nothing to set up on the server.

Among the reasons you're not receiving any acknowledges there might be:

- Your clients just do not have `XEP-0184` enabled.
- Depending on the XMPP libraries you're using (on *both* clients — the sender and the receiver), *the sender might decide to not even request receipts* if it [discovers](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html) (by querying the peer's capabilities) that it has `XEP-0184` turned off.

  To be may be more clear: XEPs usually suggest the implementations to check if the feature defined by the XEP is supported, and to not attempt to use it if it isn't.  Not all libraries and client do this, but some do.  This means that some implementations might go like this: OK, I was requested to send delivery receipt requests, so

  1. Do service discovery on the peer I'm about to contact.
  2. Check to see if it has `XEP-0184` enabled.
  3. If not, I'll just silently not attach any receipt requests.

  Whether a particular XMPP library does this *by itself* depends on how "smart" is was made.

If by `XMPP Framework` you mean [this library](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework), please try to read its source code to see if it's "smart" and asks the peer for its caps and then checks to see if `XEP-0184` is enabled.

Also check to see if you can enable logging of XML streams exchanged by your client.  Inspecting them is the best way to debug XMPP-related issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [XEP-0022](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0022.html) Message events extension to achieve this:

Here your message stanza formate:

```
<message to='username@domain.com' id='msgId-21102012,12:12:11'>
  <body>How are you doing?</body>
  <x xmlns='jabber:x:event'>
    <offline/>
    <delivered/>
    <composing/>
  </x>
</message>
```

Based on receipnt status, open fire will respone with message event status. Once look into XEP-022 extension.

Comment: `XEP-0022` is obsolete (while certainly useful with some server implementation like `ejabberd` to get notified about the message being stored in offline storage etc).

Comment: @kostix I am using ejabberd server, so XEP-0022 will work with that ? If you have any link related to XEP-0022 objective-c version please provide us